# get div's stored in array x,y position

Tags: jquery, position, offset, scrollto, scrolltop

I'm developing my website and I have a button (position: fixed) and each time I click it I need it to scroll the page to the next div which has class="picture" and is first below the scrollTop().top value.
I store the divs with class="picture" in $pictures array, but I'm not sure if it's needed...

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

  var $pictures = $('.picture');

  var i;

  $(window).scroll(function()
  {
    for(i in $pictures)
    {
      if($("html").scrollTop() > $pictures[i].offset().top)
      {
        alert(i);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

unfortunately it doesn't work.
Maybe someone has better aproach?

Thanks!

Comment: Hmm... why are you manually iterating over the selector object instead of just using jquerys .each() method?

Comment: I think that a jsFiddle would help here in answering he question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Aside from the misguided `for-in` loop, you need to compute `$(window).scrollTop()` instead of `$('html').scrollTop()`, which always equals zero.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $pictures = $('.picture');

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        $pictures.each(function(i, el) {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > $(this).offset().top) {
                console.log(i);
            };
        });
    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/Uysmz/

This will log the index number of EVERY picture that's scrolled up off the screen. Alternatively, if you only wanted the LAST picture that had scrolled off screen, you could use a `.filter` function instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $pictures = $('.picture');

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        $justpast = $pictures.filter(function(i, el) {
            return ($(window).scrollTop() > $(this).offset().top);
        }).last();
        console.log($justpast.index());
    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/RuR6R/